# rake db:migrate error at digital ocean and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my app on digital ocean platform. 
May be the problem is with  devise.
I am using postgres database.

i tried running

> RAILS_ENV=production2 rake db:create

but its giving me error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `app_id' for nil:NilClass
/home/Clot-/config/initializers/devise.rb:252:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:288:in `setup'
/home/Clot-/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/Clot-/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: do you have the production2 env configured in database.yml and have you added a file for it in environments?

Comment: yes it isproduction 2

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you missed adding the field app_id on the devise user model?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a migration specific error. It looks like a nil error. It looks like you're trying to access the field 'app_id' of nil. Try looking through your initialization files for where this might happen, especially

> /home/Clot-/config/initializers/devise.rb:252:in